# How to use buttons awt/close window?

Tags: java, button, fonts, awt, textarea

Good evening!
I have a problems with understanding, how to use realisation of buttons (awt)
How can i increase font like answer on every my click, not just once?
P.s. how can i realise textArea just in border of my frame(300x300) with a place for buttonPanel on south?

```
    public class GUI extends Frame {

    public GUI() throws HeadlessException {
        Frame frame = new Frame();
        frame.setVisible(true);
        frame.setTitle("Test window");
        frame.setSize(300, 300);

        frame.addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void windowClosing(WindowEvent e) {
                //System.exit(0);
                frame.dispose();
            }
        });

        String fontName = "Arial";
        int fontStyle = 10;
        int fontSize = 12;

        Font font = new Font(fontName, fontStyle, fontSize);
        Panel mainPanel = new Panel();
        Panel textPlacePanel = new Panel();
        Panel buttonPlacePanel = new Panel();
        Button increaseButton = new Button("Increase");


        Button decreaseButton = new Button("Decrease");
        Label label = new Label("Font size");
        TextArea textArea = new TextArea();
        textArea.setFont(font);

        frame.add(mainPanel,BorderLayout.CENTER);
        frame.add(buttonPlacePanel,BorderLayout.SOUTH);
        frame.add(textPlacePanel,BorderLayout.CENTER);

        buttonPlacePanel.add(label);
        buttonPlacePanel.add(increaseButton);
        buttonPlacePanel.add(decreaseButton);
        textPlacePanel.add(textArea);

        increaseButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                int i = font.getSize();
                Font font = new Font(fontName,fontStyle,++i);
                textArea.setFont(font);
            }
        });
        decreaseButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                int i = font.getSize();
                Font font = new Font(fontName,fontStyle,--i);
                textArea.setFont(font);
            }
        });

    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        GUI gui = new GUI();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How can i increase font like answer on every my click

So, your problem is here...

```
int i = font.getSize();
Font font = new Font(fontName, fontStyle, i);
```

You are using the instance of `font` you created in the constructor, but then you create a new local instance of the `Font` (within the context of the `ActionListener`) and apply that to the `TextArea`, which means the base size is always 12.

Instead, make use a `Font#deriveFont`

```
public class GUI extends Frame {

    private Font font;
    // Don't use hard coded values, use the constent names, its easier
    // to read
    private int fontStyle = Font.PLAIN;
    private int fontSize = 12;

    public GUI() {
        String fontName = "Arial";
        font = new Font(fontName, fontStyle, fontSize);

        //...
        increaseButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                font.deriveFont(++fontSize);
                textArea.setFont(font);
            }
        });
        //...
```

> how can i realise textArea just in border of my frame(300x300) with a place for buttonPanel on south?

`BorderLayout` will only manage the last component added to one of the five available positions it manages.  I don't know what `mainPanel` is doing, but it's kind of pointless so I'd get rid of it.

Also, the default layout for a `Panel` is `Flowlayout`, not sure why you're wrapping the text area in one, but I'd change the layout managers to something more useful

```
Font font = new Font(fontName, fontStyle, fontSize);
//Panel mainPanel = new Panel();
Panel textPlacePanel = new Panel(new BorderLayout());
Panel buttonPlacePanel = new Panel(new GridLayout(1, 3));
Button increaseButton = new Button("Increase");

Button decreaseButton = new Button("Decrease");
Label label = new Label("Font size");
TextArea textArea = new TextArea();
textArea.setFont(font);

//frame.add(mainPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
frame.add(buttonPlacePanel, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
frame.add(textPlacePanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
```

I would also make use of `pack` over `setSie`, but that might require some additional configuration and since AWT hasn't been in main stream use for 17 years, I don't care to try and remember what you might need to do to correct.  Word of advice, consider using Swing or JavaFX instead, you'll get better support

Comment: *"consider using Swing or JavaFX instead, you'll get better support"* +++ (though the support offered here was excellent - OP lucked out ***this*** time)

Comment: thank you very much! it's a very helpful and useful answer! yeah, i know about Swing and JavaFX...awt- it's just like a point in my education fron teacher and after awt ofc we are going to use Swing and JavaFX. But how teacher was talking all of it- add-ons for AWT.
btw, mainpanel should contain two others panels
p.s.Do you know maybe, why can i see reuslt on my frame just when changing window size??

Comment: @Montego Call `setVisible` last